# C++: "Error: Pointer being freed was not allocated" when handling large lists

Tags: c++, list, vector, malloc, runtime-error

I am trying to process some data in a std::vector made of 2D points; basically, I need to check whether or not all points are, directly or indirectly through another point, linked by a certain relationship that I don't think needs to be detailed here.

In order to process my data properly, I copied the data from the vector and used lists for faster handling.

I wrote the following 2D vector class:

```
class float2D {
public:
    float x, y;

    float2D(): x(0), y(0) {}
    float2D(int a, int b): x(a), y(b) {}

    bool CheckStuffWith(float2D &u); // does some math
};
```

The code used to process data looks like this:

```
bool CheckStuffInVector(vector<float2D> const &data) { 
    if (data.size() < 2) return true;

    // Copy the data in a list, will be thinned out progressively
    list<float2D> data_copy(data.begin(), data.end());

    // Points used to CheckStuff with the remaining points in data_copy
    list<float2D> processed_data;

    // Choose arbitrarily the last element to compare with the others
    processed_data.push_back(data_copy.back());
    data_copy.pop_back();

    list<float2D>::iterator it1;
    list<float2D>::iterator it2 = data_copy.begin();

    while (!processed_data.empty()) {
        it1 = processed_data.begin();
        if (it1->CheckStuffWith(*it2)) {
            // *it2 fulfills the relationship
            // Remove the point from data_copy
            // and put it in processed_data
            processed_data.push_back(*it2);
            data_copy.erase(it2);
        } else {
            // Move on to the next point to process
            it2++;
        }
        if (it2 == data_copy.end() && !data_copy.empty()) {
            // We checked all the necessary stuff with *it1
            // No need to keep it in processed_data
            processed_data.pop_front();
            it2 = data_copy.begin();
        } else if (data_copy.empty()) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return data_copy.empty();
}
```

This runs fine with relatively low values for `data.size()`, but I need it to work for bigger values. When the vector's size is 1,000,000, I get the following runtime error:

`malloc: *** error for object 0x7fac0e341240: pointer being freed was not allocated`

I can't figure out where that comes from. I probably overlooked something, but I can't see what it is; I figured an outsider's look might help :)

I also want to point out that such a problem could be handled using a tree structure, but because of the size of the problem, that might cause the tree's height to be very big (thus, risk of stack overflow?) and the fact that I want something that runs fast, I thought I'd be better off doing it this way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two things : You don't need to define your own copy constructor/assignment operators for `float2d`. And consider (for example) what happens if `data` has just one element: `data_copy` will then be empty before your loops starts, and you'll basically attempt to `erase(data_copy.end())`

Comment: @Roddy: Thanks for your answer! If `data` has only one element, the function should return true with no additional computations, as specified on the first line: `if (data.size() < 2) return true;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a `data_copy.erase(it2)` you invalidate iterator it2, then you dereference the iterator in the next iteration of the while loop. This is UB.

I suggest you resolve this with replacing the erase line with this

```
it2 = data_copy.erase(it2)
```

which will replace the it2 iterator with a valid iterator pointing to the next element or the data_copy.end() if the list is empty.

Comment: You're right! I hadn't spotted this, and it was probably causing a few problems. Thank you! I'm going to check whether or not it works fine now (too bad the program runs super slow now, for some reason, so i'll have to wait a long time...).

Comment: Okay, this was the source of the problem. My code is super slow, but this was the cause. Thanks!